# Scraping HTML with JSoup, getting HTTP error, status 456

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I am trying to scrape a site (www.oddsportal.com) with JSoup, but i have run into an issue.

```
String url = "http://www.oddsportal.com/matches/";      
Document doc = null;
System.out.println("Connecting to " + url + "...");
try {
    doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
} catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

When i connect and do a "get" i get the following:

```
 Connecting to http://www.oddsportal.com/matches/...

       org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=456, 
       URL=http://www.oddsportal.com/matches/
            at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:435)
            at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:410)
            at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:164)
            at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:153)
```

What could be the cause? It seems there is no HTTP 456 status code, so i assume it's some sort of site-specific code?
There is a login function at the site but it is not mandatory for viewing the content.
Other sites i have tried works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you include the `user agent` it will work, from [documentation](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html):

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://example.com").userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0").get();
```

Comment: Documentation linked doesn't mention anything about HTTP status code 456